# AngularJS HTTP error codes with $q.all()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

I have a bunch of http requests like this:

```
$q.all([$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: urlOne,
    headers: {Authorization: "Token " + jqToken}
}), $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: urlTwo,
    headers: {Authorization: "Token " + jqToken}
})])
    .then(function (results) {
        //do stuff
    });
```

However urlOne and urlTwo (and a bunch of others) may under some conditions return 403. In this case everything just freezes and then() function is never executed. How can I handle 403 responses? 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "everything just freezes?"

Comment: The `then` function of a promise takes two arguments, a success and an error callback -- add then second function to catch your errors: `.then(function(result) { // success }, function(err) { // error });`

Comment: @Jacob execution stops and `.then(function(results){})` is never executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need to handle errors.

```
$q.all([...])
  .then(
    function (results) {
      // Handle success
    }, function (err) {
      // Handle errors
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! Another question:
I'm writing results of requests to local storage. How should I set error handling to skip 403'ed responses?

Comment: It sounds like you want to handle the response for each individually. `q.all` is going to produce an error the first time any of the promises are rejected. If you don't want this to happen, I'd attach a results handler to each request.